# Executing functions one after another properly in Corona?

Tags: function, coronasdk

So I've been trying for a few days now to figure this out. I'm making a sort of simple block code game with Corona and I can't get the functions for the play button to actually play in order. I have nine different boxes that should play the action put into them one after the other but instead, everything plays all together in one big mush of a function.
The code for it is a bit long though since it's supposed to detect what block function is or isn't there.

```
---------------------------------------------

-----button image------

local play = display.newImage ("GoButton.png")
    play.x = display.contentWidth /2 - 140
    play.y = display.contentHeight /2 + 20

------later used Variables---

local b1 = 0
local b2 = 0
local b3 = 0
local b4 = 0
local b5 = 0
local b6 = 0
local b7 = 0
local b8 = 0
local b9 = 0

-----Play button code-----


function play:tap ( event ) 


function play1 ()
-------------------------Box 1------------------------------------------
    if b1 == 0 then
        Mascot.alpha = 1
        end

    if b1 == 1 then
        Mascot:applyLinearImpulse( 1, 0, Mascot.x, Mascot.y )
        end

    if b1 == 2 then
        Mascot:applyLinearImpulse( -1, 0, Mascot.x, Mascot.y )
    end

    if b1 == 3 then 
        Mascot:applyLinearImpulse( 0, -1, Mascot.x, Mascot.y )
    end

    if b1 == 4 then
        Mascot.alpha = 0.5
    end

    if b1 == 5 then
            Mascot.xScale = -1
        end
    end


function play2 ()
-------------------------Box 2------------------------------------------
    if b2 == 0 then
        Mascot.alpha = 1
        end

    if b2 == 1 then
        Mascot:applyLinearImpulse( 1, 0, Mascot.x, Mascot.y )
        end

    if b2 == 2 then
        Mascot:applyLinearImpulse( -1, 0, Mascot.x, Mascot.y )
    end

    if b2 == 3 then 
        Mascot:applyLinearImpulse( 0, -1, Mascot.x, Mascot.y )
    end

    if b2 == 4 then
        Mascot.alpha = 0.5
    end

    if b2 == 5 then
            Mascot.xScale = -1
        end


end
timer.performWithDelay( 5000, play2)

function play3 ()
-------------------------Box 3------------------------------------------
    if b3 == 0 then
        Mascot.alpha = 1
        end

    if b3 == 1 then
        Mascot:applyLinearImpulse( 1, 0, Mascot.x, Mascot.y )
        end

    if b3 == 2 then
        Mascot:applyLinearImpulse( -1, 0, Mascot.x, Mascot.y )
    end

    if b3 == 3 then 
        Mascot:applyLinearImpulse( 0, -1, Mascot.x, Mascot.y )
    end

    if b3 == 4 then
        Mascot.alpha = 0.5
    end

    if b3 == 5 then
            Mascot.xScale = 1
        end
end
timer.performWithDelay( 5000, play3)

function play4 ()
-------------------------Box 4------------------------------------------
    if b4 == 0 then
        Mascot.alpha = 1
        end

    if b4 == 1 then
        Mascot:applyLinearImpulse( 1, 0, Mascot.x, Mascot.y )
        end

    if b4 == 2 then
        Mascot:applyLinearImpulse( -1, 0, Mascot.x, Mascot.y )
    end

    if b4 == 3 then 
        Mascot:applyLinearImpulse( 0, -1, Mascot.x, Mascot.y )
    end

    if b4 == 4 then
        Mascot.alpha = 0.5
    end

    if b4 == 5 then
            Mascot.xScale = -1
        end

end
timer.performWithDelay( 5000, play4)

function play5 ()
-------------------------Box 5------------------------------------------
    if b5 == 0 then
        Mascot.alpha = 1
        end

    if b5 == 1 then
        Mascot:applyLinearImpulse( 1, 0, Mascot.x, Mascot.y )
        end

    if b5 == 2 then
        Mascot:applyLinearImpulse( -1, 0, Mascot.x, Mascot.y )
    end

    if b5 == 3 then 
        Mascot:applyLinearImpulse( 0, -1, Mascot.x, Mascot.y )
    end

    if b5 == 4 then
        Mascot.alpha = 0.5
    end

    if b5 == 5 then
            Mascot.xScale = -1
        end

end
timer.performWithDelay( 5000, play5)

function play6 ()
-------------------------Box 6------------------------------------------
    if b6 == 0 then
        Mascot.alpha = 1
        end

    if b6 == 1 then
        Mascot:applyLinearImpulse( 1, 0, Mascot.x, Mascot.y )
        end

    if b6 == 2 then
        Mascot:applyLinearImpulse( -1, 0, Mascot.x, Mascot.y )
    end

    if b6 == 3 then 
        Mascot:applyLinearImpulse( 0, -1, Mascot.x, Mascot.y )
    end

    if b6 == 4 then
        Mascot.alpha = 0.5
    end

    if b6 == 5 then
            Mascot.xScale = -1
        end
end
timer.performWithDelay( 5000, play6)

function play7 ()
-------------------------Box 7------------------------------------------
    if b7 == 0 then
        Mascot.alpha = 1
        end

    if b7 == 1 then
        Mascot:applyLinearImpulse( 1, 0, Mascot.x, Mascot.y )
        end

    if b7 == 2 then
        Mascot:applyLinearImpulse( -1, 0, Mascot.x, Mascot.y )
    end

    if b7 == 3 then 
        Mascot:applyLinearImpulse( 0, -1, Mascot.x, Mascot.y )
    end

    if b7 == 4 then
        Mascot.alpha = 0.5
    end

    if b7 == 5 then
            Mascot.xScale = -1
        end

end
timer.performWithDelay( 5000, play7)

function play8 ()
-------------------------Box 8------------------------------------------
    if b8 == 0 then
        Mascot.alpha = 1
        end

    if b8 == 1 then
        Mascot:applyLinearImpulse( 1, 0, Mascot.x, Mascot.y )
        end

    if b8 == 2 then
        Mascot:applyLinearImpulse( -1, 0, Mascot.x, Mascot.y )
    end

    if b8 == 3 then 
        Mascot:applyLinearImpulse( 0, -1, Mascot.x, Mascot.y )
    end

    if b8 == 4 then
        Mascot.alpha = 0.5
    end

    if b8 == 5 then
            Mascot.xScale = -1
        end
end
timer.performWithDelay( 5000, play8)

function play9 ()
-------------------------Box 9------------------------------------------
    if b9 == 0 then
        Mascot.alpha = 1
        end

    if b9 == 1 then
        Mascot:applyLinearImpulse( 1, 0, Mascot.x, Mascot.y )
        end

    if b9 == 2 then
        Mascot:applyLinearImpulse( -1, 0, Mascot.x, Mascot.y )
    end

    if b9 == 3 then 
        Mascot:applyLinearImpulse( 0, -1, Mascot.x, Mascot.y )
    end

    if b9 == 4 then
        Mascot.alpha = 0.5
    end

    if b9 == 5 then
            Mascot.xScale = -1
        end 

 b1 = 0
 b2 = 0
 b3 = 0
 b4 = 0
 b5 = 0
 b6 = 0
 b7 = 0
 b8 = 0
 b9 = 0

    if walk == 1 then
        walkSpawn:removeSelf()
        walk = 0
    end

    if attack == 1 then
        attackSpawn:removeSelf()
        attack = 0
    end

    if jump == 1 then
        jumpSpawn:removeSelf()
        jump = 0
    end

    if flip == 1 then
        flipSpawn:removeSelf()
        flip = 0
    end

    if face == 1 then
        faceSpawn:removeSelf()
        face = 0
    end

end
timer.performWithDelay( 5000, play9)

print ("derp")

Runtime:addEventListener("enterFrame", play1)
Runtime:addEventListener("enterFrame", play2)
Runtime:addEventListener("enterFrame", play3)
Runtime:addEventListener("enterFrame", play4)
Runtime:addEventListener("enterFrame", play5)
Runtime:addEventListener("enterFrame", play6)
Runtime:addEventListener("enterFrame", play7)
Runtime:addEventListener("enterFrame", play8)
Runtime:addEventListener("enterFrame", play9)

end

play:addEventListener("tap", play)


---------------------------------------
```

If anyone could help that'd be a huge favor, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Ok! First of all, I don't think you understand what an "enterFrame" listener does.
When you add the code

```
Runtime:addEventListener("enterFrame", play1)
```

For each frame of the game ( about 30 frames are executed every sec), the function play1 is executed.   In the above code you have added an "enterFrame" listener **FOR EACH FUNCTION** and **ON EVERY TAP EVENT**    .So each function will be called every frame multiple times.  Unless I am very much mistaken,  that is probably not what you want.

Since you already call the functions using

```
timer.performWithDelay( 5000, play<n>)
```

You should remove the Enterframe listeners.

What exactly are you trying to achieve here?   If you can be more specific, it would be easier to help you

Comment: Thanks for rresponding.

When I remove the EventListeners the function doesn't respond at all.

I'm trying to create a sort of Coding Simulation game like Scratch coding and I've got the "code" Blocks that you can drag into a box. Depending on the order the user has the blocks in I want the robot to take the appropriate actions when the Play button is pressed. There are only nine possible spots to drag the blocks into and five different functions because I wanted to keep it fairly simple.